# out of range for vm-bytes stress-ng

Tags: bash, stress-testing

we are using the following:

- stress-ng: 0.07.16-1
- Debian: 9.13
- kernel: 4.19.133

I wanted to start a stress test on a machine with 1.5 TB of RAM. Usually we start the stress-test:

```
sudo systemd-run --slice=system.slice stress-ng -m64 -c64 -f64 --vm-bytes $(awk '/MemAvailable/{printf "%d\n", $2 * 0.9;}' < /proc/meminfo)k --vm-keep --timeout 48h
```

And this time I got back this error:

```
Value 1 is out of range for vm-bytes, allowed: 4096 .. 4294967296
```

Can someone help me out here ?

kind regards,

Pascal den Bekker

Comment: Try with "$(awk '/MemAvailable/{printf "%d\n", $2 * 0.9;}' < /proc/meminfo)k"

Comment: Sorry my mistake the correct command should be:sudo systemd-run --slice=system.slice stress-ng -m64 -c64 -f64 --vm-bytes $(awk '/MemAvailable/{printf "%d\n", $2 * 0.9;}' < /proc/meminfo)k --vm-keep --timeout 48h. And the error also appears with that :-(